# Oracle.Data.AccessClient not installed even though it is

Tags: powerbi

I installed the oracle client using the provided documentation but powerbi keeps telling me that it is not.
Maybe I need to set some specific environment variable?
Right now oracle is installed in c:\oracle

Comment: Hi, what version of Power Bi Desktop are you using? is it msi installer or the microsoft store?

Comment: hello it's the msi version

Comment: Check your PATH environment variables. I let oracle install in default folder, I have something like this in path:
C:\app\client\....\product\12.1.0\client_1